# How can i make a youtube subscribe button with new tab and get a value after close the window?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I like to give a YouTube Subscription button in my website, what will open in a new tab and after subscribe or close the tab my website will get a value for confirmation the user subscribe my channel or not.
Please help me to do this. I can't find any thing.
Thanks in advance.
Thank You.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.   Stack is not a coding service we are not going to do it for you.  Show us what you have tried and we will try to help

Comment: You won't get that information by redirecting them to your youtube channel. You're going to have to implement sign in by google and ask them them to click the button you put on your page which will subscribe them to your channel. Something like this - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert

Comment: no code example required... even using Google's own example at https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button doesn't open a new window like Google suggests it should in the Overview page: "the YouTube channel page opens in a new window"